# Grab and Rotate proxies in Python

Tags: python, proxy, bots

I'm creating a **bot** to register in a *webform*, I need to **grab proxies** from certain websites like *proxyscrap* and download them into a **text file**.
Then the python script **runs** the browser and **defines** then **connect** to the **working and fastest one first**.

Can I do that?
If yes please provide me with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have other method is free method not like proxyscrap. I suggest to use http-request-randomizer from here [Link](https://pypi.org/project/http-request-randomizer/)

Using it is so simple

```
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy import RequestProxy

req_proxy = RequestProxy()
pro=req_proxy.randomize_proxy()
pro1=str(pro).split(' ')[0]
```

Then use pro1 as a proxy for your request it will generate new proxy each time, or if you need to use a custom proxy then:

```
def is_bad_proxy(pip):    
try:
    proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': pip})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    req=urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com')  # change the URL to test here
    sock=urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print 'Error code: ', e.code
    return e.code
except Exception, detail:
    print "ERROR:", detail
    return True
return False
```